# I need to subtract a value using the value of a number type input, what would be the easiest way to do this?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a financial control application, and I have a problem, I have an input type number and I have two radio inputs, one for income and the other for expenses, when I insert a value in the input type number and mark the input radio income and repeat this value he has to add the values

```
I have an image to show
```

[this is illustrative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weMUJ.png)

similarly, I have a radio input for expenses, and the value that I enter in it has to be subtracted from the total income, but I am not able to do that

I have an illustrative image[this is the image of the expenses section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT0ab.png)

this is my javascript code:

```
const buttonAdd = document.querySelector('[data-js="buttonAdd"]')
const inputAdd = document.querySelector('[data-js="inputAdd"]')
const containerText = document.querySelector('[data-js="container-text"]')
const incomeInput = document.querySelector('[data-js="income-input"]')
const expenseInput = document.querySelector('[data-js="expense-input"]')
const descriptionContainer = document.querySelector('[data-js="description"]')
const inputNumber = document.querySelector('[data-js="input-number"]')

let zeroBase = 0

buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  
  let inputNumberToValue = Number(inputNumber.value)
  let finalValueIncrement = zeroBase += inputNumberToValue;
  

    if(incomeInput.checked){
        containerText.innerHTML = finalValueIncrement;
        inputNumber.value = ''
    }
    if(expenseInput.checked){
        containerText.innerHTML = finalValueIncrement - inputNumberToValue 
        inputNumber.value = ''
    }

})
```

Comment: if you want answers, [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and check-> **Help others reproduce the problem**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`let finalValueIncrement = zeroBase += inputNumberToValue;` this line adds your input to your current value. If you then subtract the input from that new current Value you get what you started with.

Quick example: let's assume our current value is 0 and our input is 5:

```
buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  
  let inputNumberToValue = Number(inputNumber.value) // inputNumberToValue == 5
  let finalValueIncrement = zeroBase += inputNumberToValue; //finalValueIncrement == 5
  

    /*if(incomeInput.checked){
        containerText.innerHTML = finalValueIncrement;
        inputNumber.value = ''
    }*/
    if(expenseInput.checked){
        containerText.innerHTML = finalValueIncrement - inputNumberToValue //containerText.innerHTML == 5 - 5 == 0
        inputNumber.value = ''
    }

})
```

To fix this move your addition into the appropiate if condition.

And please change the name of `zeroBase` to `currentValue` (becaue that's what it is) and the proper/descriptive name would have made it way easier to see what's actually going on (But that last bit's just my opinion)

The way I would write the code is as follows:

```
let currentValue = 0 

buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  
  let inputNumberToValue = Number(inputNumber.value)

    if(incomeInput.checked){
        currentValue += inputNumberToValue;
        inputNumber.value = ''
    }
    if(expenseInput.checked){
        currentValue -= inputNumberToValue;
        inputNumber.value = ''
    }
    
contaienrText.innerHTML = currentValue

})
```

Please note, that your function is impure (meaning it has sideeffects)

Comment: @FernandoOliveira yes and no; I'm pretty sure the reason I suggested is the one that causes the error. My code however will not work (since `=-` and `=+` are wrong syntax - just switch it to the right syntax and it should work) - and btw. try not to just copy and paste my code ... try to understand what the issue was (I explained it above) and try to correct your code based on the issue I described

Comment: thanks my friend it worked, at first your suggestion was going wrong by the operator you entered as =+ when I inverted it to += it worked perfectly.